# Create a table together with nested objects (columns)

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, nested

In my Spring MVC application I am trying to build a complex form, where a table and the tables columns can be created at once.

When I submit my form, the table is created with all attributes, but it has not columns. Whats wrong with the nested objects?

This is my view:

```
<form id="form2" class="form-horizontal" action="/Weasy/virtualtable/insert" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" id="isVirtual" name="isVirtual" value="true"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="query" name="query" value="select * from aktie"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="schema" name="schema" value="40"/>


        <div class="form-group">

        <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>Column No</i></label>
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>Column Name</i></label>
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>Database Type</i></label>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>0</i></label>
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>ID</i></label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">

                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[0].name" value="ID" placeholder="specify name">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[0].datatype" value="INTEGER , Size: 11" placeholder="specify datatype">


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>1</i></label>
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>BESCHREIBUNG</i></label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">

                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[1].name" value="BESCHREIBUNG" placeholder="specify name">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[1].datatype" value="VARCHAR , Size: 255" placeholder="specify datatype">


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>2</i></label>
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>ISIN</i></label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">

                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[2].name" value="ISIN" placeholder="specify name">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[2].datatype" value="VARCHAR , Size: 255" placeholder="specify datatype">


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>3</i></label>
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>WKN</i></label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">

                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[3].name" value="WKN" placeholder="specify name">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[3].datatype" value="VARCHAR , Size: 255" placeholder="specify datatype">


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>4</i></label>
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>NAME</i></label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">

                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[4].name" value="NAME" placeholder="specify name">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[4].datatype" value="VARCHAR , Size: 255" placeholder="specify datatype">


                </div>
            </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name"><i>Source Table</i></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"
                    value="" placeholder="Virtual Table Name" required>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input id="execQry" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default"
                        type="submit" value="Save"
                        >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And this is the corresponding method of my controller. When I debug it, I see the table, but it has no columns.

```
@RequestMapping("insert")
public ModelAndView insert(@ModelAttribute SrcTable obj) {
    return update(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you are trying to simulate a table with bootstrap, if you take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms in **form-horizontal** section it can give you a more table-like structure, but in this case i recommend a table structure inside your form.

Example:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="isVirtual" name="isVirtual" value="true"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="query" name="query" value="select * from aktie"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="schema" name="schema" value="40"/>

    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><i>Column No</i></th>
          <th><i>Column Name</i></th>
          <th><i>Database Type</i></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><i>0</i></td>
          <td><i>ID</i></td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[0].name" value="ID" placeholder="specify name">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[0].datatype" value="INTEGER , Size: 11" placeholder="specify datatype">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><i>1</i></td>
          <td><i>BESCHREIBUNG</i></td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[1].name" value="BESCHREIBUNG" placeholder="specify name">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[1].datatype" value="VARCHAR , Size: 255" placeholder="specify datatype">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><i>2</i></td>
          <td><i>ISIN</i></td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[2].name" value="ISIN" placeholder="specify name">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[2].datatype" value="VARCHAR , Size: 255" placeholder="specify datatype">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><i>3</i></td>
          <td><i>WKN</i></td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[3].name" value="WKN" placeholder="specify name">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[3].datatype" value="VARCHAR , Size: 255" placeholder="specify datatype">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><i>4</i></td>
          <td><i>NAME</i></td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[4].name" value="NAME" placeholder="specify name">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[4].datatype" value="VARCHAR , Size: 255" placeholder="specify datatype">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input id="execQry" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default"
    type="submit" value="Save"
    >
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint - and I will follow it - but it won't influence the described issue, will it?

Comment: It will, in your server side you dont need to worry with the view structure, only with its content. Just make sure your controller has received the appropriated content.

Comment: the view is a table now, like you suggested. However, the columns are still not persisted with the table. And I cannot agree with you, that changing from bootstrap to html could fix this issue.

Comment: Sorry for not helping, please mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

While looking this over after a day pause, I found my error.

instead of

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="obj.columns[4].name" value="NAME" placeholder="specify name">
```

I had to use

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="columns[4].name" value="NAME" placeholder="specify name">
```